How Do I set up double Integrals for joint distributions?
I've been trying to learn joint distributions and have run into a hard wall in this problem.
Two different and independent bus routes come to the same stop, then both continue to the train station. From route X, there are typically, 2 buses arriving every 10 minutes. While buses from route Y will arrive at the stop with uniform randomness anywhere from between 0 to 10 minutes since the last bus from route Y.
You arrived at the stop just in time to miss the previous bus, which happened to be from route Y ...
(a) What is the probability that a Bus from route X will arrive before the next Bus from route Y ? (find the joint distribution and set up the integral, no need to evaluate)
This one was simple enough to find, as I know we are looking for P(X<Y). Thusly:
$\displaystyle 
\int_{0}^{7} \int_{0}^{y} (0.2e^-0.2x)) \, dx \, dy
$
(That e to the power of -0.2x)
b, however, is much harder:
(b) What is the probability that the next bus from route X and the next bus from route Y will arrive within a minute from each other? All I need to do is find the limits,
Which means I need to solve P( abs(X-Y) < 1), which is in the form:
$\int_{A}^{B} \int_{C}^{D} f(x) \, dx \, dy$ + $\int_{E}^{F} \int_{G}^{H} f(x) \, dx \, dy$
Which is where I'm completley stuck. All I was able to figure out is A = 0, and [B,C] = [0, y+1].
Can Anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

You have been able to use mathJax in some of the formulas. Why not e^{-0.2x}? Another question: Why that upper bound $7$ in $\int_{0}^{\color{red}7} \int_{0}^{y} (0.2e^{-0.2x})) , dx , dy,?$

Notation:

$\lambda=0.2$ expected number of buses from line $X$ per minute;

$\delta=10$ end of the time interval in which bus from $Y$ arrives with uniform
probability once a bus from $X$ has arrived;

$a=1$ absolute difference between arrival of $Y$ and the next buss from $X\,;$


The joint density is
$$\tag1
\lambda\,e^{-\lambda x}\frac1\delta 1_{\{x<y<x+\delta\}}\,.
$$
The probability that the next bus from $X$ arrives before $Y$ is
$$\tag2
\mathbb P(X<Y)=\frac1\delta\int_0^{\delta}\int_0^y\lambda\,e^{-\lambda x}\,dx\,dy=\frac1\delta\int_0^\delta1-e^{-\lambda y}\,dy=1-\frac{1-e^{-\lambda\delta}}{\delta\lambda}\approx0.5677\,.
$$
The probability that the next bus from $X$ and $Y$ arrive within $a$ minutes is
$$\tag3
\mathbb P\Big(Y-a<X<Y+a\Big)=\mathbb P\Big(Y<a;0<X<Y+a\Big)+\mathbb P\Big(a<Y;Y-a<X<Y+a\Big)\,.
$$
The first probability in (3) is
\begin{align}
&\mathbb P\Big(Y<a;0<X<Y+a\Big)
=\frac1\delta\int_0^a\int_0^{y+a}\lambda\,e^{-\lambda x}\,dx\,dy=\frac1\delta\int_0^a 1-e^{-\lambda(y+a)} \,dy\\[2mm]
&=\frac a\delta-e^{-\lambda a}\frac{1-e^{-\lambda a}}{\delta\lambda}\,.\tag4
\end{align}
The second probability in (3) is
\begin{align}
&\mathbb P\Big(a<Y;Y-a<X<Y+a\Big)=\frac1\delta\int_a^\delta\int_{y-a}^{y+a}\lambda\,e^{-\lambda x}\,dx\,dy=\frac1\delta\int_a^\delta e^{-\lambda(y-a)}-e^{-\lambda(y+a)}\,dy\\[2mm]
&=\frac{1-e^{-\lambda(\delta-a)}-e^{-2\lambda a}+e^{-\lambda(\delta+a)}}{\delta\lambda}\,.\tag5
\end{align}
Their sum is
$$
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Bigg|}\mathbb P\Big(Y-a<X<Y+a\Big)=\frac a\delta+\frac{1-e^{-\lambda(\delta-a)}-e^{-\lambda a}+e^{-\lambda(\delta+a)}}{\delta\lambda}\approx 0.1634\,.\quad}\tag6
$$
